# convert String to int with with parseint

Tags: java, string, int

I try to convert int String to int

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
```

`tokens[2]` contain a `String` `"12777"`
But I got this error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2019" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
 input string:
 "12777" 

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499) 
at inet.ChildServer.hopen(ChildServer.java:88)  
at inet.ChildServer.run(ChildServer.java:51)
```

Edit: Sorry the characters are invisible in eclipse, I don't Understand what is this.
I have a String in this form

```
command1|Destination-IP|DestinationPort
```

and I just splot it

```
String[] tokens = sentence.split( "[|]" );
```

Comment: All those characters after the last 7 do not belong there ...

Comment: If you look at your stack trace, I guess the reason _should_ be quite self-evident...

Comment: That string has some extra chars... lol

Comment: ...so maybe you should `trim` before splitting?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with informations you posted. Try posting actual input you are using and full but short code that reproduces your problem (from my experience people often find root of their problems while creating such code example). More info at [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you trim the string before pass to Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]); it may contain blank spaces.

Comment: you are suggesting work around. It is not a real solution. The real solution is to understand the source of the garbage.

Comment: If it prints the number, trim won't remove the possible garbage?

Answer (score 0):

As have guys already mentioned your string does not contain `12777` as you think. It contains `12777` and then a lot of garbage that prevents parsing of your string to int. Debug your code to understand what is the source of this garbage. Take a look on code that assigns value to `tokens[2]`.

If you have problems there post the code that assigns value to `tokens[2]`.

Good luck.

EDIT

OK, you have posted yet another part of your code. But the problems seems to be before this point. Take a look on code that assigns value to `sentence`.

BTW: you can see everything in eclipse. Expand the string and see the character array stored into the string.

Comment: It worked with tirm, I recive the String via socket from a perl client, maybe perl use some extra char for strings ..

Comment: @user567, sounds strange. If you can check the perl script, do it. I believe that the bug is there.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful you can have errors after you

```
String x = "123";
Integer.parseInt(x);
```

do

```
String x = "jonas";
try{
Integer.parseInt(x.trim());
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //do something creative with the error
}
```